# When navigating to files, use existing persp-mode perspective if one exists

Tags: persp-mode

If for example I visit an org file in a [`persp-mode.el`](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el) perspective A, then in a different perspective B run `org-open-at-point` to visit that same file path, I would like that to open in perspective A.

That org command is my main use case, but I would be happy with an answer that showed how to do this with persp for any similar navigation command: I think this question is really about persp-mode, not about org.

Perhaps this is the sort of thing that `persp-def-auto-persp` should help with, but I have the feeling nobody understands how to use that.  Maybe there's some other way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean [perspective.el](https://github.com/nex3/perspective-el) or something else?

Comment: Sorry I mean persp-mode.el, I've corrected the question